# Confused about the usage of .apply and lambda

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

After encountering this code: 
[image]

I was confused about the usage of both `.apply` and `lambda`. Firstly does `.apply` apply the desired change to all elements in all the columns specified or each column one by one? Secondly, does x in `lambda x:` iterate through every element in specified columns or columns separately? Thirdly, does `x.min` or `x.max` give us the minimum or maximum of all the elements in specified columns or minimum and maximum elements of each column separately? Any answer explaining the whole process would make me more than grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: All elements in all columns specified. x is applied on a per column basis. `x.min()` and `x.max()` I have no knowledge of. They will have no wider scope than the column which `apply` is currently applying to.

Comment: @John I see. `x.min()` and `x.max()` parts are really interesting actually. Because if x is an element, then how is any of these functions supposed to indicate the min or max of the whole columns?

Comment: it isn't possible without iterating the whole column, it's nice to know Pandas offers to do this, potentially, in C. I'd have just coded the python to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is the best avoid `apply` - loops under the hood and working with subset of `DataFrame` by columns from `list`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)

c = ['B','C','D']
```

So first select minimal values of selected columns and similar maximal:

```
print (df[c].min())
B    4
C    2
D    0
dtype: int64
```

Then subtract and divide:

```
print ((df[c] - df[c].min()))
   B  C  D
0  0  5  1
1  1  6  3
2  0  7  5
3  1  2  7
4  1  0  1
5  0  1  0

print (df[c].max() - df[c].min())
B    1
C    7
D    7
dtype: int64

df[c] = (df[c] - df[c].min()) / (df[c].max() - df[c].min())
print (df)
   A    B         C         D  E  F
0  a  0.0  0.714286  0.142857  5  a
1  b  1.0  0.857143  0.428571  3  a
2  c  0.0  1.000000  0.714286  6  a
3  d  1.0  0.285714  1.000000  9  b
4  e  1.0  0.000000  0.142857  2  b
5  f  0.0  0.142857  0.000000  4  b
```

EDIT:

For debug `apply` is best create custom function:

```
def f(x):
    #for each loop return column
    print (x)
    #return scalar - min
    print (x.min())
    #return new Series - column
    print ((x-x.min())/ (x.max() - x.min()))
    return (x-x.min())/ (x.max() - x.min())

df[c] = df[c].apply(f)
print (df)
```

Comment: I see, so when we say `.apply(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / (x.max() - x.min())`, both `x.min()` and `x.max()` values are obtained after lambda x iterates through everything right? And also, they apply to each column separately (like in your answer)?

Comment: `apply` working with each colum separately - x is column, then get scala min and scalar max and return new column.

Comment: If that is the case, then it makes sense because we want to normalise each column separately.

Comment: @Huzo - Yes, also non loop solution return same output.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the data are really being normalised. Because x.min and x.max may simply take the min and max of a single value, hence no normalisation would occur.

Comment: `Max and min return the max and min values for the selected column, per column. ` I did not get this part. Can you elaborate more? so those values are returned once x iterates through the whole series?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my understanding of the problem.